# updating last not blank record SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset.

```
ID    var1    var2    var3 
1     100     200     
1     150             300 

2             120                
2     100     150     200   

3     200             150             
3     250    300
```

I would like to have a new dataset with only the last not blank record for each group of variables.

```
id    var1    var2    var3
1     150     200     300              
2     100     150     200               
3     250     300     150
```

last. select the last reord, but i need to selet the last not null record

Comment: Images are not helpful anyways. If you want code we'd have to type it out and the code and that's a bit inconsiderate. Please post your data as text and include what you've tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want the last non missing value for each non-key variable. So you can let the `UPDATE` statement do the work for you.  Normally for update operation you apply transactions to a master dataset. But for your application you can use `OBS=0` dataset option to make your current dataset work as both the master and the transactions.

```
data want ;
  update have(obs=0) have ;
  by id;
run;
```

Comment: Nice twist Tom!

Answer (score 0):

Riccardo:

There are many ways to select, within each group, the last non-missing value of each column.  Here are three ways.  I would not say one is the best way, each approach has it's merits depending on the specific data set, coder comfort and long term maintainability.

#### Way 1 - UPDATE statement

Perhaps the simplest of the coding approaches goes like this:

- make a data set that has one row per id and the same columns as the original data.
- use the `UPDATE` statement to replace each like named variable with a non-missing value.

Example:

```
data want_base_table(label="One row per id, original columns");
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id;
run;

* use have as a transaction data set in the update statement;
data want_by_update;
  update want_base_table have;
  by id;
run;
```

#### Way 2 - DOW loop

Others will involve arrays and first. and last. flag variables of the `BY` group.  This example shows a `DOW` loop that tracks the non-missing value and then uses them for the output of each `ID`:

```
data want_dow;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    array myvar var1-var3 ;
    array myhas has1-has3 ;

    do _i = 1 to dim(myvar);
      if not missing (myvar(_i)) then 
        myhas(_i) = myvar(_i);
    end;
  end;

  do _i = 1 to dim(myhas);
    myvar(_i) = myhas(_i);
  end;

  output;

  drop _i has1-has3;
run;
```

A loop is most often called a `DOW` loop when there is a `SET` statement inside the `DO; END;` block and the loop termination is triggered by the `last.` flag variable.  A similar non DOW approach (not shown) would use the implicit loop and `first.` to initialize the tracking array and `last.` for copying the values (tracked within group) into the columns for output.

#### Way 3 - Merging column slices

```
data want_by_column_slices;
  merge
    have (keep=id var1 where=(var1 ne .))
    have (keep=id var2 where=(var2 ne .))
    have (keep=id var3 where=(var3 ne .))
  ;
  by id;
  if last.id;
run;
```